Как откомпилировать пакет, процедуру, функцию без внесения изменения Oracle?
Допустим, есть некий огромный пакет, и я внес туда изменнения.
Я хочу откомпилировать без внесения изменения, просто хочу проверить на ошибки. Так сказать, есть ли возможности у Oracle виртуальной компиляции, что даже если нет ошибки, в базе не сохранился пакет?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Например я написал новую процедуру и при компиляции хотелось бы проверить ошибки, но сама процедура не должна создастся в базе оракл)))

Ну назовите его другим именем, каким-то временным, этот тестовый пакет, потом удалите )
